# Storing a SQL query in a variable to use in robotframework?

Tags: python, sql, selenium, robotframework

I am trying to store the results of a query in a variable and then after performing some other functionality. Confirming that is hasn't changed.

Does anyone know if something like that is possible?

Edit:

What I've tried to do so far is create the ARGUMENT variable and tried to assign it to a page element. But of course, this is failing.

I assume I need to retrieve the figure using a second script before running my robot test? I'm quite new to using robot so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Create a variable `temp = results` after you get your results.   After you do your work with your results and when all is said and done do a `if temp != results:` to handle cases where your results data was modified.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: Whoops... sorry for that JeffC... added to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.
I never used it, but it must be similar to this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT blabla FROM myTab")
rows = cursor.fetchall() # rows is now something like this [(1, 100, "abc'def"), (2, None, 'dada'), (3, 42, 'bar')]
tempRows = rows    

# perform other operations on rows

if tempRows == rows:
    print "nothing is changed"
else:
    print "rows is changed"
```